# Imagick or header issue in wordpress and save that image to specific directory

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i write some code for images to be put side by side.I use Imagick library for that purpose.This is my code.

```
$im = new Imagick();
// session contain image path like upload/my.jpg
$im->readImage("http://localhost/wordpress3.5/".$_SESSION['imgname']);
$im->readImage("http://localhost/wordpress3.5/".$_SESSION['preimgurl']);

$im->resetIterator();
$combined = $im->appendImages(false);

/* Output the image */
$combined->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $combined;exit();
```

But the output is not what i suppose to be.this is output.I write this code under the plugin/ files.Also i want to save that image to directory like "localhost/wordpress/uplaod_pic/".
[image]

Comment: I can see a button `Add to cart`. You need to remove that button and only have this image alone.

Comment: If you want both to show, you need to use `<img>` tags or base64 images.

Comment: @DaveChen i use this code echo "<img src='".$combined."' />";exit(); but didn't work same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an image tag with the `src` tags containing the direct or base64 version of the image.

First example would be direct:

```
echo '<img src="http://localhost/wordpress3.5/'.$_SESSION['imgname'].'">';
```

Second would be using base64 with the [data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), [PHP Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Inclusion_in_HTML_or_CSS_using_PHP):

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($combined).'">';
```

I would recommend the first method, simply because it looks like a product display, the images are most likely public and hotlinking can be busted if you choose.

In both examples, since the image is inline, you wouldn't need to set the content-type to an image.

You should also place the correct mime type within the second version, either `image/png`, `image/jpeg` or others depending on the image.

**Edit**: To extend this:

`$combined` contains the image, so you want to save this, simple use:

```
file_put_contents('upload_pic/'.$time().'.png', $combined);
```

Comment: Thanks thats working but how can i save that image to some path like "uploads/" ? Because this base64 code is not just simple to save.

Comment: If you upload the images, have the images be uploaded to `/uploads/*.*`, or manually move static images to that folder. You can use `../` to go back a directory and use `../uploads/` to reach the correct folder.

Comment: Sorry not get your point clearly.I use this code but fails $file = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($combined).'">';
$newfile = '"upload_pic/'.time().png;
if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}

Comment: Check the edit. Also please explain `$file`, it's not found anywhere in the original question.

Comment: I try these codes .file_put_contents("http://localhost/wordpress3.5/upload_pic/txtsd.png", $combined);
$file = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($combined).'">';
file_put_contents("http://localhost/wordpress3.5/upload_pic/txt.png", $file);

Comment: You can not create files with the public url. You should use `file_put_contents("wordpress3.5/upload_pic/txtsd.png", $combined);`. Please open a new question or edit your existing one.

Comment: Have you tried using the private path instead of the public uri? An example is the comment before.